# Running Magento locally

Tags: php, mysql, magento, localhost, homestead

I want to run a project from a client locally for development for obvious reasons.

This is a Magento shop and I've made a copy of the `/public` folder and the database. Put the `/public` contents in a Homestead box and imported the database, as it should work just fine for other non-laravel projects which use PHP, MySQL etc, right?

I changed the secure and insecure URL's in the database config table and it seems to work mostly.

The only problem seems to be that when I go to sitename.app:8000/**admin** it opens the admin page, but when I log in, it redirects to sitename.nl/admin, so the live version..

How does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have fixed it already!

go to `/public/var/cache` and delete all the contents.

First load will be slow because it has to regenerate them but the links will now work as expected!

Comment: You could also try `sitename.local:8000` this specifically tells your browser to only use a local ip address.

Comment: Also you can set your Magento environment to developer if using 2 via CLi commands or via the Admin Panel if using less than 2. This saves you from caching contents and deleting them all the site - better to not cache when working in a development environment. +1 for trying yourself

Comment: Thanks for the tips!